# Is there any benefit in stretching with weights?

Tags: stretching, weights, isometric

The kind of stretching I'm referring to is the sort some schools make their kids do at morning assembly. Skip through parts of this video to get a general idea. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-uadHt_oyM

In a nutshell, the stretching involves standing with feet shoulder width apart and moving your arms up/down/around. So doing this with weights seems like a dynamic version of holding your arm straight out with a heavy weight (known to be a good shoulder workout).

Is there a benefit to doing these with a weight in either hand. Has anyone done this?

Comment: I believe this is a great idea. See my question: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/39723/can-i-increase-flexibility-by-strengthening-muscles. That is theory. In practice I unfortunately somehow do not find much time for stretching. Much to busy theorizing about physiology probably.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that doing the exercises in the given video with weights is good at all. These are supposed to be done without weights. Weight loading should be done in the exercises that we naturally do, such as: horizontal / vertical push pull, hinge, and squat. Rotating your shoulders with a weight in your hand is not beneficial. We should not forget that not everyone has developed motor control skills, and children usually lack these skills.

Therefore I say that doing these with weights has no benefits. On the contrary, I believe it increases risk of injury.