# does strength gain (without muscles getting bigger) lead to greater flexibility?

Tags: muscle, strength, injury, flexibility, rehabilitation

I notice that after injury people lose their flexibility. Rehab exercises will strengthen the injured muscle and also make the recovering person more flexible.

But is this also the case when a regular, non-injured, person is trying to strength their muscles? Would they also become more flexible in the process?

Comment: From personal experience, I have found my flexibility to have improved as a result in strength training. This is worth a read also: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/39723/36850